# Conditional formatting - highlighting in VBA

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, highlight

I am trying to make the VBA that highlights the entire row if the row contains a word "New".

The applying range of conditional formatting, I am trying to put maybe A1 till AZ2000

the reason, I also had a problem setting range as whole worksheet.

I never learned VBA so I am getting information from internet

I wrote this much but it is not working, to my knowledge, it should work but i don't know why it is not working, it is frustrating how, I fix one, and another problem comes up...lol

```
Sub Highlighting()

  'Definining the variables:
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim condition1 As FormatCondition

 'Fixing/Setting the range on which conditional formatting is to be desired
  Set rng = ("A1, AZ2000")

  'To delete/clear any existing conditional formatting from the range
   ws.FormatConditions.delete

  'This is where I get Syntax error, it says "New" needs list separator
  Set condition1 = ws.FormatConditions.Add(xlConditionValueFormula, xlGreater, "=FIND(""New"",$AF1)>0)")

  'Defining and setting the format to be applied for each condition
   With condition1
    .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 10498160
   End With

End Sub
```

[image]

this is how i want it set up in VBA

Comment: I believe you may need `xlExpression` instead of `xlGreater`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That is the answer. Make an official answer so this can be closed out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add

Comment: Hi thank you for the advice, but i also had an error message at "Set rng = ("A1, AZ2000") it says type mismatch, is it because i have set the wrong range?

Comment: Maybe `"Set rng = ("A1:AZ2000")"`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

I don't know which workbook you apply this to so I given you some options, Remove the `'` before `set wb` or `sheetID` depending on which ones you're going with (and add it to the others). If you're interested on some more common tips and tricks for coding with vba [check out this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

```vb
Sub Highlighting()

'Definining the variables:
Dim rng As String
Dim condition1 As FormatCondition
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheetID As String

'Define workbook to run code against, depending on which fits you comment out/in here:
Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' the excel workbook that contains the vba code
'set wb = Workbooks("nameOfExcelWorkbook.xlsx") ' excel workbook that you've defined (must be an open workbook with the name.file ending inside citation marks)
'set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' the currently selected excel workbook (not recommended)
'Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Filename as string.fileEnding")

'Define what sheet to use
sheetID = ActiveSheet.Name 'currently selected worksheet name (not recommended)
'sheetID = "nameOfSheet"
'sheetID = 1 ' indexed version of above

'Fixing/Setting the range on which conditional formatting is to be desired
rng = "A1:AZ2000"


With wb.Sheets(sheetID).Range(rng)

    'To delete/clear any existing conditional formatting from the range
    .FormatConditions.Delete

    'Apply conditional formating
    Set condition1 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=FIND(""New"",$AF1)>0")

End With
'Defining and setting the format to be applied for each condition
With condition1
    .Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
End With

End Sub
```